# Call Websocket based on submitted IP

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, websocket

I'm currently working on an application using jQuery mobile and Phonegap that uses websockets. Inside my html, I've got a form where the user can enter the IP  of the server they want to connect to. This is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#connect').submit(function(){
    var ip = $('#iptext').val();
    var wsuri = "ws://" + ip + ":9021/ws";
    jQuery.mobile.changePage('#index', { allowSamePageTransition: true });

    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        sock = new WebSocket(wsuri);
    } else if ("MozWebSocket" in window) {
       sock = new MozWebSocket(wsuri);
    } else {
       log("Browser does not support WebSocket!");
       window.location = "http://autobahn.ws/unsupportedbrowser";
    }

    ellog = document.getElementById('log');

    if (sock) {
       sock.onopen = function() {
          log("Connected to " + wsuri);
       }

       sock.onclose = function(e) {
          log("Connection closed (wasClean = " + e.wasClean + ", code = " + e.code + ", reason = '" + e.reason + "')");
          sock = null;
       }

       sock.onmessage = function(e) {
          log("Got echo: " + e.data);
          parseMessage(e.data);
       }
    }

});

});
```

The form is submitted properly, but the connection to the server closes immediately with Error code 1006. if I put the code for the websocked outside of the submit function, everything works fine. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I've tried calling the websocket both from a regular onclick-event on a button, without jQuery mobile, and with AJAX disabled. Same behavior.

Comment: Does it work normally without jquery-mobile? If yes, then it could be `ajax` problem, thus, `ajax` should be disabled for jquery-mobile.

Comment: No, it doesn't...I've tried just calling it with an onClick-Event on a button, same behavior. I tried disabling AJAX nonetheless, but it still closes immediately.

Comment: How did you actually test 'everything works fine'? Sure about that? Because simple connect upon button click without any jquery and ajax techniques should definitely work and is part of many simple hello world websocket examples.

Comment: Well, it connects to the server properly and immediately, sending and receiving messages works as well...so I couldn't imagine that there's anything wrong with the connect itself. But other than that, I can only make assumptions, so fair enough!